# Broken login.keychain, what now?

Tags: macos, keychain

I recently moved computers, and since then I can no longer import certificates into my login keychain. I have:

- Tried using Keychain First aid
- Tried running reset password in recovery mode to reset permissions
- Tried running disk first aid and resetting permissions

None of these have helped. I still get **[UNIX]Permission Denied** when I try to import.

So I tried a few other experiments:

- I tried deleting old passwords from the keychain. that worked fine
- I made a new keychain, development, and imported the certificate there. that worked fine too.

So for whatever reason, something is wrong with my login keychain. Is there a way to export everything and re-import into a new copy? I looked on the Apple web site, but it's hopelessly out of date.

Comment: There's a *small chance* that if you're experiencing the same issue, your certificates are actually importing, but are showing up under a different name than you expect. Double check and you may find this is the case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps someone in the future:

The *list* of keychains, notably `login.keychain`, is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist`

The `system.keychain` and similar are found in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist`

If those files have wonky permissions, you'll have problems doing anything. Even if the keychain files themselves are fine, if the OS is unable to edit those two files it just silently fails in weird ways. Notably, Keychain Access will keep forgetting about the whole login chain, and anything you add or remove from it.

This same problem may apply to the keychain itself; if you can't save to it, you likely have wonky permissions.

Note that it appears Disk Utility does **not** fix this, although I don't know why. It seems you have to manually fix this. You can do this by doing a Get Info on a root folder and reapplying permissions. In my case the problem was that the Owner was wrong because I moved the files from another machine.

Comment: After speaking the head of Mac support at Apple, he had everything fixed in a couple of minutes. Look at any older file in your account and Get Info. In the security section, is there a "custom"? If so, select your root user folder, get info, add admin readonly, you read/write and everyone read only, then click the gear and apply to all enclosed. Fixed. Disk Util should do this for you, but doesn't.

Comment: Works perfectly as mentioned. Saved my day. :) Tons of thanks! :) :)

Comment: they don't seem to exist in Mac Monterrey

Answer (score 0):

Create a new login keychain and copy the contents of the old keychain into the new.

1. Close Keychain Access. Open **Terminal** and make a backup of your login keychain.

   `cp ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain{,-old}`

   - You now have two keychains in your keychain folder named `login.keychain` and `login.keychain-old`. The latter is an identical copy of the original keychain.
2. Move `login.keychain` to your desktop and rename it with the following command:

   `mv ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain ~/Desktop/login1.keychain`
3. Now, create a new, empty login keychain:

   `touch ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`
4. Exit Terminal. Open Keychain Access. *The login keychain will be empty.*
5. On your Desktop, double click `login1.keychain`
6. Within Keychain Access, unlock `login1.keychain` and copy all of its contents into the new, empty `login.keychain`
7. Right click (or <kbd>Control</kbd> + click) `login1.keychain` and select "Delete References and Files"
8. Attempt to import your certificates.

Comment: Ok, I've done this and I have the certs in the keychain. Yay! Here's the remaining issue: when I quit Keychain Access and re-open it, the login keychain is missing. It still works, apps save passwords properly (it seems), but its never in the list. I suspect this list is locked? Where is this list stored?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz in Keychain access, once you open in, right click in the side bar. Are you presented with the option "Make login keychain default"? If so, click it and test. I would also suggest running keychain first aid again. If still it won't show up, from menu bar in Keychain Access > Edit > Keychain List > Show: User > click the + sign and add the login keychain path

Comment: My apologies if this dups. When I open keychain access, login is not there. So I go to the keychain list, press + and select it. It appears in the list in the main window, and is bold as the default. This is why I think the problem is not the keychain but the file where keychain access saves this list.

Comment: That said, I can't save my iCloud password. Everything else seems fine.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz  You are referring to [this list](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2jfngxu.jpg), correct? I would try resetting the login keychain through keychain access itself if you're still having trouble. Keychain Access > Preferences > General > Reset My Default Keychain. Then, import contents from the old into the new. In retrospect, this is a better method.

Comment: That list as well, but more specifically the one that is on the upper left of the screen when I first open Keychain Access. Actually, it was Reset My Default Keychain that set all of this off.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz you need to add the keychain to the list in the screenshot manually. It should automatically open in your keychain list from then on. If not backup contents according to first instruction. Reset keychain within keychain access. Reimport keychain contents into new keychain again...

Comment: I did all of these steps. The same thing happens again!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz i'm stumped. going to try to mess around on a VM and get back to u if I can find a workaround. Keychain Access should recognize the default keychain and open it automatically.

Comment: I believe the problem is related to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391911/os-x-keychain-not-visible-to-keychain-access-app-in-mavericks I think the problem is that I don't have write access to the file that stores the keychain paths.

Comment: Ok so I found the problem. It's permissions on com.apple.security.plist in the Library/Preferences. When I moved from the old machine I ended up with permissions problems, and I guess Disk Util didn't find this one.